# Destructure an object parameter two levels?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So, I'm passing an object to an ES6 function that I'd like to **destructure** down to the parameter of a parameter. For example, the code below will log the `data` prop of `stuff`, but I'd like it to log the `things` prop of `data` of `stuff`. So the correct answer would log `[1,2,3,4]`. Not confusing at all, I know. Anyone know if this is possible?

```
const stuff = {
   data: {
      things: [1,2,3,4]
   }
};
const getThings = ({ data }) => {
   console.log(data)    
};
getThings(stuff);
```

Comment: https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-destructuring-in-depth

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Sure, here's how:

```js
const stuff = {
   data: {
      things: [1,2,3,4]
   }
};
const getThings = ({ data: {things} }) => {
   console.log(things)    
};
getThings(stuff);
```

Comment: what if you want to have a reference to data and things after the same deconstuction? or do you two seperate deconstruction statements?

Comment: Why would you need to, since you can do `{ data: {things, otherThings} }`?

Answer (score 10):

As I correctly understood you, the correct answer is:

```
const getThings = ({ data: { things } }) => {
   console.log(things)    
};
```